# Facebook Marketing API : Duplicate images in Carousel ads in /adcreatives?fields=asset_feed_spec endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to retrieve all the images from the ad. If an ad has multiple placements, Facebook generates different hashes for all the images. I need all the distinct images.

The ad includes a carousel with 4 images, but when I check the specified endpoint, it shows 9 images in the asset_feed_spec. These images have different hashes due to multiple placements. Is there a way to get all the distinct images?

API endpoint: <ad_id>/adcreatives?fields=asset_feed_spec